# how in maven multiple folders to the multiple zip archives with the same names

Tags: maven

I want to collect the project module using, Maven
I have a directory structure. Folders can be added dirN:

```
project-module
 |
 |-dir1
 |-dir2
 |-dir3
 |-...
 |-dirN
 |-bin.xml
 |-pom.xml
```

I tried the maven-assembly-plugin

pom.xml

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>bin.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sql dir</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

bin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>../mspost-db</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
            <!--<outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>-->
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

DESIRED OUTCOME
Each directory to be packaged into a single zip archive folder with the same name, that is.

```
project-module
 |
 |-targer
   |-dir1.zip
   |-dir2.zip
   |-dir3.zip
   |-...
   |-dirN.zip
```

help me please.

Answer (score 2):

The [iterator-maven-plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/) could be used to work with a single assembly descriptor:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>iterator</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <items>
          <item>dir1</item>
          <item>dir2</item>
          <item>dir3</item>
        </items>
        <pluginExecutors>
          <pluginExecutor>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <goal>single</goal>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/bin.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <finalName>${item}</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </pluginExecutor>
        </pluginExecutors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then reference `${item}` in the `bin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>${item}</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/${item}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This results in `target/dir1.zip` etc.

Instead of listing the `<items>` explicitly, it can also iterate over a `<folder>`, though I don't see a way that could be restricted to such as `dir*`.

(Edit start)

E.g. to iterate the (immediate) subdirectories of `parentDir`:

```
  <configuration>
    <folder>${project.basedir}/parentDir</folder>
    <pluginExecutors>
    ... as above ...
```

The assembly descriptor (`bin.xml`) can then reference something like `<directory>${project.basedir}/parentDir/${item}</directory>`, much as before.

The lack of a filter would still be an issue if iterating over `<folder>${project.basedir}</folder>` though - this would zip up the `target` directory too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Suppose I would like to iterate over a <folder>, how will I use it in the bin.xml file?